# Serre's condition $(S_n)$ locus is stable under generalization?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, zariski-topology

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and $n\ge 1$ an integer. Consider the set $S_n^R:=\left\{\mathfrak p \in \text{Spec}(R) \text{ }| \text{ } \text{depth } R_{\mathfrak p} \ge \inf \{n, \dim R_{\mathfrak p}\}\right\}$.

Then, is it true that $\text{Spec}(R)\smallsetminus S_n^R$ is a specialization closed subset of $\text{Spec}(R)$? ,i.e., if $\mathfrak p \subseteq \mathfrak q$ are prime ideals of $R$ such that $\mathfrak p\notin S_n^R$, then must it hold that $\mathfrak q\notin S_n^R$  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meta-answer: this is elementary- and reasonable-sounding but not in Stacks so it’s probably false.

Actual answer: let $R=k[x,y,z]/(yz,z^2)$. Then $x$ is a regular element so $(x,y,z) \in S_1^R$.

But $(y,z)$ (which isn’t minimal) is the annihilator of $z$ so $(y,z) \notin S_1^R$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you happen to know if $S_n^R$ itself is specialization-closed ?

Comment: It can’t be the case: if $R$ is a domain, then the generic point is $S_n^R$ for any $n$, but for large $n$, a given prime is in $S_n^R$ iff $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay at this prime – so this would imply that $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay at any prime.